# SBT: Watch source and test source changes at the same time

Tags: scala, sbt

We can make SBT watch for changes like `sbt ~compile`. However if we do `sbt ~compile` it doesn't watch for changes to the test sources.

I can make it watch the test sources `sbt ~test:compile`. but I want to watch both at the same time.

I tried `sbt ~compile ~test:compile` but this only watches the sources. it doesn't watch the test sources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sbt ~test:compile` should watch (and compile) both `Compile`-scope sources (`src/main/`) and `Test`-scope sources (`src/test/`).The latter [depends](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+the+configuration+axis) on the former.